# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I have this generic method

```
class Foo { 
     public static bar<T>(x: T): T {
         ...
         if(x === null)
             return null; //<------- syntax error
         ...
     }
 }


... //somewhere
const x = Foo.bar<number | null>(1);
```

I'm getting the syntax error

> TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'.

I'm expecting this to compile because `T` could be `null`.

what is the proper way to solve this problem

Comment: When in doubt, the compiler is right.

Comment: @gnasher729 obviously not. For example compiler cannot know about all runtime checks for null.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You have to declare the return type as `null` or turn off `strictNullChecks` in your tsconfig

```
public static bar<T>(x: T): T | null
```

or you could type null `as any` e.g.

```
 return null as any;
```

Comment: `const x : number = Foo.bar<number>(1);` this will fail compiling

Comment: @Ali assigning the result to something of type `number` should fail to compile. That's the point of the null checking. If your function can return `null` it means you should only be able to assign to a nullable `const x: number | null` and that way you will be forced to check for `null` before using the number.

Comment: @Duncan yes I agree with you , but I'm returning null only when I have `foo<number|null>`, when `foo` take any type but `null` there is no null value returned

Comment: Well I don't know why but assigning the default value to `null as any` fixed my issue with my `not assignable to type 'object'` error--danke

Answer (score 66):

Since version 3.9.5, TypeScript enforces `strictNullChecks` on `numbers` and `strings` just to name a few. For example, the following code will throw an error during compilation:

```typescript
let x: number = null;
```

To avoid this error you have two options:

- Set `strictNullChecks=false` in `tsconfig.json`.
- Declare a union type `number | null`:

  ```typescript
  let x: number | null = null;
  ```

Comment: Removing the checks doesn't solve the problem on how to fix it. It's like removing the battery from your smoke alarm.

Comment: @JonasStensved did you check what number two does? I don't encourage removing checks and that is why I included solution two as well.

Comment: using `any` is essentially removing type checks so yes, that is a not a good solution. Declare it as `number | null` if you need to be specific.

Comment: I've been using nulls in values without problem with typescript 4+ for ages without any strictNullChecks and for the first time ever I get an error. Typescript can be a lifesaver but it's also very unreliable at times, I cast to any, yet another exception; also I am getting it onto an "object", not a string or number.

Comment: Just to be more pricese, strictNullChecks must be added to the compilerOptions in tsconfig.json file

Comment: This is the right answer, to make Typescript work you have to define the type as any thereby defeating the whole point of Typescript.

Answer (score 18):

You can put

```
return null!;
```

It worked for me

Comment: Mind to explain more on this?

Comment: I think it's because you assert the type with the ! symbol. Sometimes you can use this symbol to assert that you have a value, for example when you have a class that might be not yet initialized you can use class!.something to tell the compiler that you are sure that it has been initialized. You can get a runtime error tho

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator `the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded`, which means `null!` is `never`, and current typescript allows assigning `never` to any type. This doesn't actually solve the type problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose here function overloads in order to remove null case for arguments being non-nullable. Consider:

```
class Foo { 
    public static bar<T>(x: T): T // overload
    public static bar(x: null): null // overload
    public static bar<T>(x: T) {
        if (x === null) {
            return null;
        } else
            return x;
     }
 }

const x = Foo.bar(1 as number); // x is number, never a null
const y = Foo.bar(null); // its null
const z = Foo.bar('s' as string | null); // its string | null
```

So the implementation has type `T | null` but thanks to overload for types which are never null we have return type of `T` so without the null possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I found that it's actually about typescript's current limitation.

> There is currently no way to narrow a type parameter like T by checking a value like value.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68898908/10694438.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to do:

```js
class Node<T> {
    private value: T
    private next: Node<T> | null

    constructor(value: T, next: Node<T> | null = null) {
        this.value = value
        this.next = next
    }
}
```