# Angular - Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number' in Angular reducer

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 project, I have this model interface:

country.model.ts

```
export interface Country {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  capital: string;
  nationality: string;
  currency: string;
  iso_3166_2: string;
  iso_3166_3: string;
  country_flag:[''];
}
```

country.reducer.ts:

```
import { Country } from './country.model';
import { CountryActions, CountryActionTypes } from './country.actions';
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from '../index';

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
    countries: CountryState;
}

export interface CountryState {
    countries: [];
    newCountry: Country;
    countryToUpdate: Country;
    deletedCountryId: number;
    error: any;
    message: any;
    countriesByPage: any;

}

export const initialState: CountryState = {
    countries: [],
    newCountry: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        capital: null,
        nationality: null,
        currency: null,
        iso_3166_2: null,
        iso_3166_3: null,
        country_flag: null
    },
    countryToUpdate: {
      id: null,
      name: null,
      capital: null,
      nationality: null,
      currency: null,
      iso_3166_2: null,
      iso_3166_3: null,
      country_flag: null
    },

    deletedCountryId: null,
    error: '',
    message: '',
    countriesByPage: ''

};
```

I got this different errors:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'

id is highlighted

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

name, capital, nationality, iso_3166_2, iso_3166_3 highlighted

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type '[""]'

country_flag highlighted

How do I resolve these?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715119/type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error that you are getting is because the model that you create, you say that the `id` is a number the `country` is a string and when you do that you cannot assign the value `null`, I guess that you are using dummy data for testing and that is why you are assign the value `null`.

You can change that, for example you can put `0` when the type of data is number or put `''` when the type of data is a string and `[]` when is an array.