# Types narrowing with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, narrowing, type-narrowing

I would like to link 2 generics types in a function, and use narrowing for both types by checking one of them. What is the correct way to do this?

```
type A = 'A';
type B = 'B';

type AB = A | B

type ComplexType<T> = {value: T}

const f = (next: ComplexType<A>) => {}

const builder = <T extends AB>(value: T) => (next: ComplexType<T>) => {
    if (value === 'A') {
        f(next) // expect next is ComplexType<A> but got error
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to consider the case where `T` is `AB` itself: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYYKEW)

Comment: Yeah, nothing stops someone from calling `builder(Math.random()<=0.999 ? "A" : "B")({value: "B"})` and having a high chance of the wrong thing happening.  This issues is [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) and the workaround for now is probably just "use a type assertion".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently no way to narrow a *type parameter* like `T` by checking a *value* like `value`.  It is possible that `value === "A"` is true but that does not mean `T` is `"A"`.  After all, maybe `value` is of type `"A" | "B"`, say by pass ing in an expression where the compiler infers the full union type:

```
builder(Math.random() <= 0.999 ? "A" : "B") // no error
```

Here there is a 99.9% chance that you've passed in `"A"` but it's still possible that you've passed in `"B"`.  The compiler infers that `T` is `"A" | "B"`.  And therefore the `next` parameter will be of type `ComplexType<"A" | "B">`.  So there is no compiler error when you call this:

```
builder(Math.random() <= 0.999 ? "A" : "B")({ value: "B" }); // no error
```

which means the compiler is technically correct that `f(next)` might be in error.

---

There are multiple existing issues in GitHub asking for support for narrowing type parameters inside generic function bodies.  The most relevant for your code is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).  This asks for some way to tell the compiler that `T` should be *either* `"A"` *or* `"B"` and not `"A" | "B"`.  Maybe the syntax would be something like `T extends_oneof [A, B]` or `(T extends A) | (T extends B)` or something completely different.  Then perhaps when you test `value === "A"` the compiler would conclude that `T extends A`, and everything would work.  Alas, there is currently no such support.

---

For now then you just have to work around it.  If you're fairly confident nobody is going to call your `builder()` incorrectly, you could just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on:

```
const builder = <T extends AB>(value: T) => (next: ComplexType<T>) => {
  if (value === 'A') {
    f(next as ComplexType<A>) // okay
  }
}
```

---

If you really need to prevent callers from doing the wrong thing with `builder()` you could make increasingly complicated call signatures that amount to simulating the "extends one of" constraint, like:

```
type NoneOf<T, U extends any[]> =
  [T] extends [U[number]] ? never : T;
type OneOf<T, U extends any[]> =
  U extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? [T] extends [F] ? NoneOf<T, R> : OneOf<T, R> : never;

const builder = <T extends "A" | "B">(
  value: T & OneOf<T, ["A", "B"]>
) => (next: ComplexType<T>) => {
  if (value === 'A') {
    f(next as ComplexType<"A">)
  }
}

builder(Math.random() <= 0.999 ? "A" : "B"); // error now
builder2("A") // okay
builder2("B") // okay
```

but of course the compiler can't follow that inside the body of `builder` anyway (generic conditional types are hard for it to deal with) so you still need the type assertion.  Personally I'd just use your original signature with the type assertion and only revisit anything more complex if you run into invalid calls in practice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkMkG4BQpJQEIOV3Qy3Ghn0TgB88TtoBhAewFswAbCADwBUyAPLwB8BAN5QAbgEMOAVwgAuKLygBfEgGNmAOwDOwKADMCACh09gyluy59BMYQEoEosRihQAlifOWAdDLy0ACE8IgARDARLsAAFgBOzADuUBapAKIJSQmmEQASAPIA6lCMhQCqADIAIir5AJIAylD5MAAK7RkAcjEYGhja+oYARnJeHAAmEAkEQlCWEDqTerC4wqZBCsq8LvCiftxWZWycPPyQQs6uUO6ePlCbsgoI4cioLneexoeG0qs2M72S6OFwAejBUGYAGtpCAPOp+lgEiBbgixhNprkALLSeL+BLSZZsUwuASIABMUAA-FAohEoMoIrgYqYJFslHSWeonP0oJo8Zo4o8IJ8EUM9MwuP4OMwAOamUVQCGtEplSq1erNVodLrdJGkHDdXQQQpGIQAGigFQWRyWKygRJAAG0ALqieAI528V224D21bOirOnRyVgjGau320iySGaMlSYBhQQoWM2W61+gOOnQu90IBE2xbLQNeHRGeMAMSt-lrZYrswAStGoN7fcWHc7Ky3jWnzbwrY3RMpU6b+4Ph2kIHGEphBroDFAMVMZlTEPMO6t6VBaMyIhsOTsoAAyFN9jPO+lWvfuvYHCxHaynOwXCBXO9o+6+DmvRAoJBit8PwPn8ALPucgj0s4CIaAMy5YhSpi4vihLEqwpJQOSUBUrS25MiyThoMqkIzDkGDwaueTROCkIwnC5HjCuCSIXuNFQrC8JAA)

Answer (score -1):

You need to make your function `f` aware of your generic too.

Changing

```
const f = (next: ComplexType<A>) => {}
```

to

```
const f = <T extends AB>(next: ComplexType<T>) => {}
```

should work.

Comment: the idea is function "f" should work with narrowed type A