# 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | null | undefined'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

There are a number of these questions on SO, but I still can't seem to find one that helps me figure out what's going on here.

Context, I'm using Pinia (VueJS), and I'm creating a "global" store, for a whole bunch of common actions/state that exist across many modules.

```js
import find from 'lodash/find';


export interface IGenericPaginationStore<T> {
  list: T[];
  count: number;
  page: number;
  next: string | null;
  previous: string | null;
  active: T | null;
  pageSize: number;
}


// store.ts


setActive<T extends { uuid: string }>(state: IGenericPaginationStore<T>, args: { uuid?: string | null, resource?: T | null }) {
      if (args.resource) {
        state.active = args.resource

        state.list.forEach((resource: T, index) => {
          if (resource?.uuid === args.resource?.uuid) {
            state.list[index] = args.resource // **** ERROR 1 HERE ****
          }
        })

        return;
      }

    },
```

Error 1:

```
TS2322: Type 'T | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.   

'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | null | undefined'.
```

I just can't figure out why this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715119/type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-t

Comment: @pixlboy - how does this solve my problem?

Comment: Looks like a similar question has been asked here before.

Comment: What is `find`?  That doesn't seem to be declared in your code, so it's not a [mre].  If it depends on vuejs3/pinia then you might want to include imports in your question, but ideally you'd remove dependencies in order to widen the audience for your question to anyone who knows TypeScript.  Anyway the issue with ERROR 1 is that control flow narrowing doesn't persist into callbacks for non-discriminant properties, and you can work around that by copying the relevant property to its own `const` variable, like [this approach](//tsplay.dev/wQ83AW).  For ERROR 2 I have no idea without `find()`.

Comment: @jcalz - You definitely solved ERROR 1. Also, find is part of lodash. I'll keep battling with that one for now

Comment: Could you remove the parts of this question about ERROR2 and `find()` and possibly put them in a separate post?  A Stack Overflow question post should ask a single question, not multiple (questions are sometimes closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only").

Comment: @jcalz - Please put your solution into an answer for me so you can earn the rep on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the effects of checking `args.resource` for [truthiness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) does not persist into the scope of the body of the `forEach()` callback.
This is a general limitation of TypeScript's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis); it essentially is unable to cross function boundaries.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a full discussion of why this is a hard problem to solve, and why the behavior is the way it is.  In short, the compiler cannot easily be sure that `args.resource` will not get reassigned before the `forEach()` callback is called.  *We* know that `forEach()` will run immediately, but the compiler cannot know this.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#11498](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) for a feature request to allow a way to say that a callback will be run immediately.)

So the narrowing of `args.resource` from `T | undefined | null` to `T` is undone inside the callback.  And the compiler complains that you can't assign a value of type `T | undefined | null` to a property of type `T`.

---

In cases like this, the workaround is usually to create a new `const` with the value you want to type guard.  A `const` cannot be reassigned, and the compiler knows this.  So if you check that a `const` is not `null` or `undefined`, then that `const` cannot be `null` or `undefined` in all scopes, even inside some callback:

```
const resource = args.resource; // copy the value here
if (resource) {
  // resource is T here
  state.active = resource
  state.list.forEach((r: T, index) => {
    // resource is still T here
    if (r.uuid === resource.uuid) {
      state.list[index] = resource; // okay
    }
  })
  return;
}
```

Now the compiler is happy, since `resource` is seen as being type `T` inside the callback, and thus can be assigned to the property of type `T` as well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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)