# Typescript an add function with nullable argument and declaring return type by using condition type

Tags: typescript

I want to write an add function
when arguments are all null, then return null
when one of the arguments is null, then return another one
when arguments are all numbers then return their sum

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoDwEFEFMAeUuYqAzomCALYBGuATogD4UgA2bANIgEJ6HEyrWg2asOAPgAUyAFyIs3GvJ4BKeQFgAUIgX8iJcpQ7bdugPy99go+zamzF8fZ2PEKh7pXXDzz2cscfy9hOkYAb38YYEQZRABeeOdVREjXN0Ro2JoEpOM2FPDEYIzEelwoEHokfJLdAF88NlJcVLq3csrqxBp2+v9G3GbWtNLMmKkcxOTU4vSxsoqqpGQ+ppa2+bHO5ZREAGoevoHtfq1tCARSKD2ktFQpAEZEbgBmd5SAek-Qhgurm5TFDoJ4vGbfRCPf5ga6ICAJYEPfJggBMXx+KOhsNQCPuUmR3Hy6L8WiAA)

```js
function add<A extends number | null, B extends number | null>(a: A, b: B): 
  A extends null
    ? B extends null
      ? null
      : B
    : B extends null
      ? A 
      : number {
    if (a == null) {
        if (b == null) { 
            return null // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'A extends null ? B extends null ? null : B : B extends null ? A : number'.
        } else {
            return b
        }
    } else {
        if (b == null) { 
            return a
        } else {
            return a + b
        }
    }
}

const a = add(1 , 333) // number
const b = add(1 , null) // 1
const c = add(null , 2) // 2
const d = add(null , null) // null
```

why does the compiler complain like this?
the code and return type declaration are almost the same.

Comment: Because of (the error message): "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'A extends null ? B extends null ? null : B : B extends null ? A : number'.(2322)"  Which should be part of your question....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715119/type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-t)

Comment: Are you asking "why does the compiler complain like this?" or how to suppress/avoid that error?  They are two different but related questions with two different answers.  The answer to "why" is that TS lacks the feature you expect, requested at [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). The answer to "how" has various possible answers depending on whether you're trying to just stop the error (easy enough) or whether you want to refactor to a version the compiler can verify as type safe (hard/impossible).  Which is it? (Mention @jcalz if you reply, thx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jcalz. I could not figure out why `null is not assignable to type 'A extends null ? B extends null ? null : B : B extends null ? A : number'`. I know overload can avoid compiler complaints, but it actually not a real type-safe solution, because if I declare an overload like that `function add(a: null, b: null): number`, the compiler still passes it. According to the link you mentioned above, may be it impossible to implement type-safely at the current version?

Comment: Generally speaking you will probably need some unsafe code somewhere if you want to produce a value of a generic conditional type.  There is a workaround in the github issue above where you can use a general-purpose control-flow-to-conditional-type helper function such that only the helper function implementation is unsafe; if I use that workaround with your example I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wQYdYw).  But, could you please answer me so I know how to proceed: Which is your primary question? Is it "why" as your post literally asks? Or is it "how"?

Comment: ... I'm happy to write up an answer explaining things, but I want to be sure I'm targeting your actual question and not something related but unasked.  Let me know, and please mention @jcalz again if you comment so I'm notified.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use overloads:

```
function add(a: number, b: number): number;
function add<A extends number>(a: A, b: null): A;
function add<B extends number>(a: null, b: B): B;
function add(a: null, b: null): null;
function add(a: number | null, b: number | null) {
    return a === null && b === null ?  null : (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0);
}
```

Note that overloads do not type check the implementation.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9b77m)

Answer (score 0):

How is it like this?

```
function add<A extends number | null, B extends number | null>(a: A, b: B): number | null {
      if (a == null) {
        if (b == null) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return b as NonNullable<B>;
        }
      } else {
        if (b == null) {
          return a as NonNullable<A>;
        } else {
          return a + b;
        }
      }
    }
```